# Why is $\frac{dx}{dy} \neq \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have a function $y=\sqrt{x}$. Then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$.
Now if I rewrite the function in terms of y then it becomes $x=y^2$ and $\frac{dx}{dy}=2y$. Clearly $\frac{dx}{dy} \neq \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$, but why is that the case? I'm confused because we have frequently used $\frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$ in rate of change questions, and I've never been taught that that's **not** the case.

Comment: $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Simply put, $dy/dx$ is not a fraction but a notational convenience that can occasionally be abused enough for desired results. It is true, however, that $$\frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))},$$ which could have been guessed by abusing $dy/dx = 1/(dx/dy)$.

Comment: I'm embarrassed -- that was so silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it *is* true. You’ve just got some mistakes. If $y=\sqrt{x}$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$, but rather, $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. Note that this is the same as $\frac{1}{2y}$, so it is the reciprocal of $\frac{dx}{dy}$.

Answer (score 3):

It actually is true.  $y = \sqrt{x}$ gives you $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$, so $\frac{1}{(\frac{dy}{dx})} = 2 \sqrt{x} = 2y$.

On the other hand, from $y = \sqrt{x}$ you can solve for $x$ as  $x = y^2$.  Then $\frac{dx}{dy} = 2y$.  So $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{(\frac{dy}{dx})}$.